# Xcode10.1 not launching

Tags: xcode, macos

I have Mojave OS in Mac. and updating to Xcode10.1 from Xcode10.0.

But it's not launching at all. Alert is showing like below :

[image]

Comment: just remove the installed Xcode & download a new one.   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode installation seems corrupted.
Try to completely uninstall and reinstall it.